# С++ ошибка необъявленный идентификатор

Tags: c++, массивы, функции

Подскажите пожалуйста, как обойти эту проблему. Не могу понять в чём дело, значение аргумента предопределено, но он считается необъявленным.(ошибка возникает на 29 строке)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
 int sortIncrease(int a[], const int length, bool IsOn = false) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                a[i] = a[j] + a[i];
                a[j] = a[i] - a[j];
                a[i] = a[i] - a[j];
            }
        }
        cout << a[i];
    }
}
int main() {
    const int length = 10;
    int UserChoice;
    int a[length]={1,3,5,2,8,11,9,4,15,19};
    
    cout << "Choose sorting metod:\n1-> increasing\n0->decreasing"<<endl;
    cin >> UserChoice;

    if (UserChoice == '1') {
        cout << sortIncrease(a, length, IsOn = false);

    }
     



}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, такой *вызов*

```
sortIncrease(a, length, IsOn = false);
```

означает передачу в качестве третьего аргумента значения `false`, *которое одновременно присваивается переменной `IsOn`*. А переменная `IsOn` у вас в `main` и в самом деле не объявлена.

Чтоб было понятнее:

```
double x;
double y = sqrt(x = 2);
```

Здесь после второй строки переменная `x` получает значение 2, а `y` — корень из 2.

Если вы хотите передать в качестве третьего аргумента `false` — можете вообще его не упоминать, так как это аргумент со значением `false` по умолчанию, но можете и явно его указать.

```
sortIncrease(a, length, false)
sortIncrease(a, length)
```

это — два одинаковых *вызова* функции.

P.S. Использованный вами метод обмена менее эффективен, чем метод с использованием временной переменной, а главное, может не работать при больших значениях переменных, когда сумма выйдет за пределы представимых значений.